# Parallel between loops, multiple asynchronous operations in the loop, how to achieve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to handle multiple asynchronous operations in a loop. These asynchronous operations I use **await** to let them execute serially. The result I want is that the loops are serial, asynchronous operations in each loop are parallel, but the result is all stringed up. How to resolve this situation?

Sorry, I am not good at English. I translate those by google.

In each loop, I use **await** to deal with **Promise** ,which has asynchronous operation.But all are serial.

My code like this:

```
var func1 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //After 10s print(1);
    loadRes("resname_1", 
        (res)=>{print(1); resolve(res);},
        (err)=>{reject(err);});
 })}

 var func2 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //After 10s print(2); 
    //some async operation like above
 })}

 var func3 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //After 10s print(3); 
    //some async operation like above
 })}


 var test = async function(){
    //some code...;
    await func1;

    //some code...;
    await func2;
    await func3;
 }

 for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    test();
 }
```

The result I got:
111222333, total seconds: 90

What I want is:
123 123 123, total seconds: about 30

Comment: The implementation of each `func` is an important part of reproducing your problem, so please provide more than just comment stubs like `//After 10s print(1);`

Comment: If you want the outer loops to run in parallel then there is no guarantee that one will end before another begins.  You can force the individual `123` but you cannot force `123123123`.  In order to do that you will have to make everything synchronous, awaiting everything.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have changed my code.

Comment: If the loop iterations should happen in parallel, but the steps in each iteration should run serially, how would you not expect `111222333` as the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for starting the asynchronous operations concertedly then have them run concurrently, while waiting for them with `Promise.all`. Then `await` each iteration of your loop:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
     //some code...;
     const [a,b,c] = await Promise.all([
         func1(),
         func2(),
         func3(),
     ]);
     console.log(a+b+c); // to ensure the expected order
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, My question is not clear, I corrected it../(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: @yoing945 Wow, that changed the question a lot - it might have been better to accept my answer as correct and then ask a completely new question.

Comment: I rollback my question and asked a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677033/if-a-want-to-realizeparallel-between-loops-multiple-asynchronous-operations-ru)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` `test`.

If you can use [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await), you can just have this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  await test();
}
```

Otherwise, you can use [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), because, after all, `test` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
test()
  .then(test)
  .then(test)
  .then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

But note that your `test` function is executing `func1`, `func2` and `func3` **serially**. If you want to run them in **parallel**, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var test = async function() {
  await Promise.all([
    func1(),
    func2(),
    func3()
  ]);
};
```

Comment: If I want func1,func2,func3 to run serially, all test() run in parallel. Should I use like this: Primise.all([test(), test(), test()])?