# If a want to realize:Parallel between loops, multiple asynchronous operations run serially in the loop, how to write the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a mistake in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661721/parallel-between-loops-multiple-asynchronous-operations-in-the-loop-how-to-ach), causing the respondent to fail to understand what I meant. So I asked a new question again.

I need to handle multiple asynchronous operations in a loop. These asynchronous operations I use **await** to let them execute serially. The result I want is that loops are parallel, asynchronous operations in each loop run serially, but the result is all stringed up. How to resolve this situation?

In each loop, I use **await** to deal with **Promise** ,which has asynchronous operation.But all are serial.

My code like this:

```
var func1 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //After 10s print(1);
    loadRes("resname_1", 
        (res)=>{print(1); resolve(res);},
        (err)=>{reject(err);});
 })}

 var func2 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //After 10s print(2); 
    //some async operation like above
 })}

 var func3 = function(){return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //After 10s print(3); 
    //some async operation like above
 })}


 var test = async function(){
    //some code...;
    await func1;

    //some code...;
    await func2;
    await func3;
 }

 for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    test();
 }
```

The result I got: 111222333, total seconds: 90

What I want is: output 123 three times Simultaneously, each 123 is serial, total seconds 30.

Comment: Do i have this correct: you want 10 seconds to pass, then "123" to print more or less instantly, then 10 more seconds, then "123", then 10 more seconds, then "123"?

Comment: It's not what I meant.Like this:(10s)1=>(10s)2=>(10s)3, repeat it simultaneously three times@Nicholas Tower

Comment: `repeat it simultaneously three times` Does this mean you expect it to wait 10 seconds, then get "111", then 10 more seconds then "222", then 10 more seconds then "333"?

Comment: yes, the output is correct like what you said.I think of the inside of the loop body as a whole, so I describe it with 123.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but in that case it looks like your code already has the expected behavior. Please look at my answer and see if i made any mistakes adjusting your code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: @yoing945 But then "*The result I got: 111222333, total seconds: 90*" doesn't make any sense. Your current code already does output the desired `111222333`, in 30s. All that might be missing is a way to wait for the loop to finish - collect the promises returned by `test()` in an array for that and use `Promise.all` before refreshing the screen or something.

Comment: When I use wifi to download pictures, the speed is faster and I can't feel it. But when I use cell phone signal download, I found that almost all downloads using await are finished at the same time, like waiting for each other, until all the pictures are downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already has the expected behavior. You claim it takes 90 seconds to execute, but the code you provided would only take 30 seconds. Here's a reproduction of your code, with all the delays cut by a factor of 10 to speed things up. So this will wait one second, log 111, then wait one second, log 222, then wait one second, log 333. Total time, 3 seconds (corresponding to 30 seconds if i did the full durations)

```js
const delay = (duration) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
const func1 = () => delay(1000).then(() => console.log(1));
const func2 = () => delay(1000).then(() => console.log(2));
const func3 = () => delay(1000).then(() => console.log(3));

const test = async () => {
  await func1();
  await func2();
  await func3();
}

for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  test();
}
```

Comment: In my actual code, my func3 is an operation to download images from the network. When the download is complete, the screen is refreshed, but my performance is that all images are downloaded before they are refreshed(The waiting time is very long, it's a bad experience for user). Thank you very much, I will review my code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the expected behaviour is to print out :`(10s)1=>(10s)2=>(10s)3=>(10s)1=>(10s)2=>(10s)3=>(10s)1=>(10s)2=>(10s)3`. `123123123` in 90 seconds, right?

If so, the problem comes from the loop :

```
 for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    test();
 }
```

It fires **3 asynchronous calls**, each call fires `func1()` `func2()` `func3()` in order. However, the 3 asynchronous calls do not wait for each other to finish execution. For example when call A prints `1`, then at the same time call B prints `1` too. So the console outputs `111222333` after 30 seconds.

To solve the problem, make the 3 asynchronous calls to be synchronous. It can be achieved by **putting the loop in an asynchronous function, with await `test()`**:

```
const forLoop = async _ => {
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
      await test();
   }
}
```

Full example:

```js
const sleep = ms => {
  return new Promise( resolve => 
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  );
}

const func1 = function(){
    //After 10s print(1); 
    return sleep(10000).then(_ => console.log("1"));
} 

const func2 = function(){
    //After 10s print(2); 
    return sleep(10000).then(_ => console.log("2"));
} 

const func3 = function(){
    //After 10s print(3); 
    return sleep(10000).then(_ => console.log("3"));
} 


const test = async function(){
   await func1();
   await func2();
   await func3();
 }

const forLoop = async _ => {
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
      await test();
   }
}

forLoop();
```

Comment: Nicholas Tower said is right.But my code is not executed as expected .Actually performing like I replied to him, maybe my code has some logic problem， I will check it.Thanks a lot!